# When I insert a row, indirect does not update

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a summary sheet and I would like that every time I add a new sheet everything gets referenced to the summary sheet. I have used `indirect` to do this, the only flaw is that once I add a row, the formula doesn't update so I would have to update the formula each time in the summary sheet. Is there any way to fix this?

This is my formula now: `=indirect(""&A33&"H44")` 
where A33 is referencing the sheet name and H44 is what I want to be updated when I add a row in the sheet being referenced. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kIzMRbgGOx1hsKdO223tfDWSz9c20w74YaObxwlplxI/edit?usp=sharing
This is an example, Lets say I add a row above row 4 in the S5 sheet, I need the formula in the summary sheet to update from =INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!B4") tp =INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!B5"). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- try like this:

  ```
  =SUM(INDIRECT(A2&"!B5:B"))
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- or like this:

  ```
  =SUM(INDIRECT(A2&"!B5:B"&ROW('S5'!B7)))
  ```

  **note:** inserted row needs to be added **before the last** value in the range. eg. with this formula you will need to add row between **B6** & **B7** so the formula would rewrite itself to **B8**. if you add it after **B7** the formula won't extend

  [image: 0]